# Automating DataGridView_CellPainting

Tags: c#

I'm having a lot of problem trying automating this method, anyone can help me:

I want to pass parameters like this:

```
private void DGV_CellPainting (int [] ColumnIndex, string [] ImageName, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e) {}
```

Usage:

```
DGV_Cellpainting (new int [] {5, 6, 7, 8}, new string [] {"Alteracao1", "Trash_full1", "Add1", "Calc1"}, e)

private void DGV_CellPainting(int[] indiceColuna, string[] nomeImagem, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex < 0)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < indiceColuna.Length; i++)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == indiceColuna[i])
            {
                Bitmap obj2 = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(nomeImagem[i]) as Bitmap;

                using (Image img = Properties.Resources.obj2)
                {
                    e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

                    int w = img.Width;
                    int h = img.Height;
                    int x = e.CellBounds.Left + (e.CellBounds.Width - w) / 2;
                    int y = e.CellBounds.Top + (e.CellBounds.Height - h) / 2;

                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(x, y, w, h));
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Work out which picture to show based on the contents of some column in the data source. If there is no suitable column, add and populate a column in the data source

Comment: I want to make this method to put in a DLL library, to use with all my programs

Comment: Doesn't mean you can't do it that way? DGV columns have settings for which column on the data source they bind to

Comment: I was trying to put a variable inside: Image img = Properties.Resources.obj2, but I'm getting an error saying: "resources doesn't have a definition for obj2.

Comment: Already tried 1:

Comment: `object obj = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(nomeImagem[i], Properties.Resources.Culture);`

Comment: `Bitmap img = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetType().GetProperty(nomeImagem[i], BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null, null) as Bitmap;`

Comment: `Image img2 = typeof(Properties.Resources).GetProperty(nomeImagem[i], BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null, null) as Image;`

Comment: nothing worked.

Comment: Careful with getting iamges out of resources; resources is a generator so you'll constantly be creating new images if you reference resources directly

Answer (score 0):

Already fix it. I did that way:

```
public static void DGV_CellPainting(int[] indiceColuna, Image[] nomeImagem, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex < 0)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < indiceColuna.Length; i++)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == indiceColuna[i])
            {
                using (nomeImagem[i])
                {
                    e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

                    int w = nomeImagem[i].Width;
                    int h = nomeImagem[i].Height;
                    int x = e.CellBounds.Left + (e.CellBounds.Width - w) / 2;
                    int y = e.CellBounds.Top + (e.CellBounds.Height - h) / 2;

                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(nomeImagem[i], new Rectangle(x, y, w, h));
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```